# When user logs in joomla it gives error like this

Tags: php, nginx, joomla, vps

> *6979 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.23.28, server:
>
> ```
> `example.com`,
> ```
>
> request: ＂GET / HTTP/2.0＂, upstream: ＂fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-cgi-74.sock:＂, host:
>
> ```
> ＂example.com＂,
> ```
>
> referrer:
>
> ```
> `＂https://example.com/www.example.com＂`
> ```

```
it uses nginx 1.21.4 and php 7.4.33

cofinguration changes in nginx and php level but nothing is working not allowing to login
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please **Edit** the question in order to [format the text and code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) properly.